# Build Configuration for Vercel Deployment - Nested Next App within subdirectory

Tags: next.js

I created a folder structure:

AppName

- Client
- Server

Where Next.js is deployed in Client

I tried to change the root directory to Client but it is not successfully deploying the Next sample page to the domain.

How can I add a step to the build function to "cd" into the Client folder before it installs and runs build?